# Dynamic Method Dismatch concept. What is its output?

Tags: java

I am confused about this Question( written below) I think its answer should be 20 but why 10. Am I wrong if yes then anyone can guide me its flow?

```
class A
{
    int i = 10;
}

class B extends A
{
    int i = 20;
}

public class MainClass
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println(a.i); //Output of this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand in depth how an expression is solved, it is necessary to refer to the *"The Java® Virtual Machine Specification"* for example that of the [Java SE 7 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/jvms7.pdf).

> 5.4.3.2 Field Resolution
>
> To resolve an unresolved symbolic reference from D to a field in a
> class or interface C, the symbolic reference to C given by the field
> reference must first ...

but, basically, **each Type has their own Resolution Table**.

If it is known that an object is of type `A` then, the resolution table `A` will be used. If it is known that is of type `B` the table `B` will be used.

In the example:

```
static class A { int i = 10; }
static class B extends A { int i = 20; }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    A a = b;
    A c = new A();
    System.out.println("#1 A: " + a.i);
    System.out.println("#2 A: " + ((B)a).i); // (correct) downcast!
    System.out.println("#3 B: " + b.i);
    System.out.println("#4 C: " + ((B)c).i); // (wrong) downcast!
}
```

with output

```
#1 A: 10
#2 A: 20
#3 B: 20
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Test$A cannot be cast to Test$B
```

10 or 20 is taken depending on whether one table or the other is used.

An important issue is to know how to differentiate when the known type is being **considered** at compile time and when the type is being considered at run time!

The outputs #1 and #3 are known at compile time to be `A` and `B` respectivelly. This is the reason why **you get 10 or 20**.

Let me show the difference between compile time and runtime.

At **runtime** the `a` variable is really a `B` object, you can check it running

```
System.out.println(a.getClass());
```

with output

```
Test$B
```

that is, although `a` is defined to be type `A` really is an object of type `B`.

**But** at compile time you said that is `A a = b` then, **the A resolution table is written (to be used) to the JVM bytecode**, this is why you get 10 and not 20.

(Additional clarification)

Internally, an object `A` will be stored (**very grossly**) like

```
@ +--------+
  | i = 10 |
  +--------+
```

with resolution table

```
A::i := @+0    // to get i from the start position plus 0
```

an object `B` will contain their base class and itself like

```
@ +--------+
  | i = 10 |
  +--------+
  | i = 20 |
  +--------+
```

with resolution table

```
B::i := @+1    // to get i from the start position plus 1
```

the **JVM** when asked to access field `*::i` use `+0` or `+1` depending if table `A` or `B` is used.

To prove it, you could run

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
System.out.println("#1: " + a.i++);
System.out.println("#2: " + ((B)a).i++);
System.out.println("#3: " + a.i);
System.out.println("#4: " + ((B)a).i);
```

with output

```
#1: 10
#2: 20
#3: 11
#4: 21
```

Showing that there are two different variables for 10 than for 20 even if it is the same object.

Answer (score 0):

new B() return reference of object of type B which is subclass to A so it fine to assign variable or type a to reference of type B

now when we call a method on variable a which method can we access

1. method defined in class A only
2. special case if we have overloaded method in class B then any call to that method will call the class B version of this method

try to read about [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) and [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: The question is not about calling a method, but about accessing a member variable.

Comment: @Robert accessing member variable would depend on which object we call this method on